# Приложение для терминала: полноэкранный режим и печать без подтверждения

Tags: javascript, браузер

Имеется Aquarius терминал на винде и веб-страница с JS скриптом, которая открыта на экране устройства терминала. При открытии в браузере есть пара НО:

1. Печать страницы. При попытке печати появляется окно, где нужно подтвердить печать. Печать необходима в обход этого окна или без него.
2. Полноэкранный режим. Да, можно просто развернуть окно браузера на весь экран через F11. Но в таком случае, при наведении курсора в верхнюю часть экрана появляется неприятный крестик, с помощью которого можно выйти из этого режима, ну а далее начать творить что-то нехорошее. В теории, можно "нащупать" на сенсоре эту область и таким образом выйти из режима. Хотелось бы этого избежать.

Какие возможные варианты есть для решения вышеописанных проблем?

Comment: Не открывать браузер - а сделать приложение, например на electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашли решение, подходящее нам - [Kiosk](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode) mode. В целом, он открывает браузер на весь экран, перекрывая панель с пуском, скрывает верхнюю область браузера, оставляя только страницу. Запрещает выход из полноэкранного режима (по сути, выйти из браузера можно будет только через alt+tab). Пока что никаких побочных эффектов не наблюдаем.

Comment: режим kiosk как раз и предназначен для решения подобных задач (он так и называется).